# Oracle Over Partition By Query with an Outer Join to all available Dates

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, partition-by

I am developing an Oracle SQL query that finds the cumulative sum of a numeric field, grouped by two field dimensions.

I am using the SALES table from the Oracle Sales History schema as reference.

The actual query is as follows:

```
Select DISTINCT CHANNEL_ID, PROD_ID, TIME_ID, SUM (AMOUNT_SOLD) OVER (PARTITION BY CHANNEL_ID, PROD_ID ORDER BY TIME_ID) AS "Cumulative Sum" 
From SH.SALES
Order By CHANNEL_ID ASC, PROD_ID ASC, TIME_ID ASC;
```

Query result:

```
CHANNEL_ID    PROD_ID   TIME_ID      Cumulative Sum
----------    -------   ------       --------------
2             13        10-JAN-98    1205.99
2             13        16-JAN-98    2335.03
2             13        11-FEB-98    4089.16
...
```

The result of this query turns out to be OK, but it is missing one thing.

**It does not show the cumulative sum for dates when there have been no sales transactions.**

What I would need, is the following result:

```
CHANNEL_ID    PROD_ID   TIME_ID      Cumulative Sum
----------    -------   ------       --------------
2             13        10-JAN-98    1205.99
2             13        11-JAN-98    1205.99
2             13        12-JAN-98    1205.99
2             13        13-JAN-98    1205.99
...
...
2             13        16-JAN-98    2335.03
2             13        17-JAN-98    2335.03
2             13        18-JAN-98    2335.03
...
...
2             13        11-FEB-98    4089.16
2             13        12-FEB-98    4089.16
...
...
```

Comment: You need to partition outer join your query to a table/subquery of dates in order to display the "missing" rows.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below query -

```
WITH min_max_date 
     AS (SELECT Min(time_id) min_time_id, 
                Max(time_id) max_time_id 
         FROM   sales) -- fetch min and max dates 
, 
     all_dates 
     AS (SELECT To_char(DATE '2004-01-01' - ROWNUM - 1, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date_id 
         FROM   dual 
         CONNECT BY ROWNUM < max_time_id - min_time_id) 
-- generated dates between min and max dates 
SELECT t2.channel_id, 
       t2.prod_id, 
       t1.date_id, 
       SUM(Nvl(amount_sold, 0)) 
         over ( 
           PARTITION BY channel_id, prod_id 
           ORDER BY t1.date_id) 
FROM   all_dates t1 
       left outer join sales t2 
                    ON t1.date__id = t2.time_id;
```

Comment: Please fix any syntax error,, or provide insert scripts in dbfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this works:

```
with data_table1 as (
select 2 channel_id, 13 prod_id, trunc(sysdate,'YY')+rownum+mod(rownum,6)-2 time_id, 1000*rownum amount_sold from dual connect by level <=10
)
select * from data_table1;
```

| CHANNEL_ID | PROD_ID | TIME_ID | AMOUNT_SOLD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 13 | 01-JAN-21 | 1000 |
| 2 | 13 | 03-JAN-21 | 2000 |
| 2 | 13 | 05-JAN-21 | 3000 |
| 2 | 13 | 07-JAN-21 | 4000 |
| 2 | 13 | 09-JAN-21 | 5000 |
| 2 | 13 | 05-JAN-21 | 6000 |
| 2 | 13 | 07-JAN-21 | 7000 |
| 2 | 13 | 09-JAN-21 | 8000 |
| 2 | 13 | 11-JAN-21 | 9000 |
| 2 | 13 | 13-JAN-21 | 10000 |

```
with data_table1 as (
select 2 channel_id, 13 prod_id, trunc(sysdate,'YY')+rownum+mod(rownum,6)-2 time_id, 1000*rownum amount_sold from dual connect by level <=10
),
date_table2 as (select trunc(sysdate,'YY')+rownum-1 TIME_ID from dual connect by level <=(select max(time_id)-min(time_id)+1 from data_table1))
Select distinct CHANNEL_ID, PROD_ID, TIME_ID, SUM (nvl(AMOUNT_SOLD,0)) OVER (PARTITION BY CHANNEL_ID, PROD_ID ORDER BY TIME_ID) AS "Cumulative Sum" 
from data_table1 partition by (channel_id,PROD_ID) right join date_table2 using (TIME_ID)
Order By CHANNEL_ID ASC, PROD_ID ASC, TIME_ID ASC;
```

| CHANNEL_ID | PROD_ID | TIME_ID | Cumulative Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 13 | 01-JAN-21 | 1000 |
| 2 | 13 | 02-JAN-21 | 1000 |
| 2 | 13 | 03-JAN-21 | 3000 |
| 2 | 13 | 04-JAN-21 | 3000 |
| 2 | 13 | 05-JAN-21 | 12000 |
| 2 | 13 | 06-JAN-21 | 12000 |
| 2 | 13 | 07-JAN-21 | 23000 |
| 2 | 13 | 08-JAN-21 | 23000 |
| 2 | 13 | 09-JAN-21 | 36000 |
| 2 | 13 | 10-JAN-21 | 36000 |
| 2 | 13 | 11-JAN-21 | 45000 |
| 2 | 13 | 12-JAN-21 | 45000 |
| 2 | 13 | 13-JAN-21 | 55000 |